# How to set windows title in python qt?

Tags: window, pyqt, title, gnome-3, gnome-shell

I develop in pyqt and i made deb package on Ubuntu. It contain .desktop file, so it automatically add icon to main menu. When I start application windows title is correct but in gnome bar shows s_main.pyw which is name of main script in application. It is possible to set correct name in that bar?

Here's [a link to image](http://s10.postimg.org/mlfljzull/test.png)!

Answer (score 3):

I found answer. Simply you can enter name of application in constructor of QApplication object. Like this.
app = QtGui.QApplication(['Here application name'])
This name shows in gnome shell.

Answer (score 2):

Gnome required .desktop file located in /usr/share/applications or ~/.local/share/applications.

Example of myapp.desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Application Name
Comment= My application description
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Development;Education
Exec=path/to/main-script
Icon=path/to/icon
```

Name from example will be displayed in Gnome top bar. Exec is path to your main script (in your case s_main.pyw).
Also you should restart Gnome to show changes (`Alt + F2`, type `r` and `Enter`).